# Difftime between now and now throws 1hr difference (C++)

Tags: c++

Why a difftime between now and now throws one hour as a result? Shouldn't it be 0?

```
time_t diffe = difftime(now, now);
CCLOG("wow %i", localtime(&diffe)->tm_hour);
```

Result of log = "wow 1"

thks

Comment: Where is `now` initialized?

Comment: did you check the documentation at all? `difftime` returns `double` representing diff in seconds, not `time_t`. Calling `localtime` on it makes no sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`difference`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/difftime) is a double with the value `0`.

When you use a `time_t` with value `0`, this is the [`epoch`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time), which is 1970-01-01 00:00:00. When you interpret this  with [`localtime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) and a timezone one hour ahead of `GMT`, you get 1970-01-01 01:00:00, which is why you see

```
1 hour
```

"difference".

Answer (score 1):

`difftime` returns a `double` (number of seconds), not a `time_t`.

`localtime`, on the other hand, takes a `time_t*` argument. Passing a `double*` would not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

`difftime` returns the difference in seconds(double). `localtime` on the other hand initializes a `tm` structure using the value provided. So my guess is that you are executing the code at `GMT+1` timezone. To get the difference in hours simply print `difftime(now, now) / (60.0 * 60.0)`